# How to add column value plus users input in PHP update query

Tags: php, mysql

Not sure if this is even possible, I am trying to get it to where "ItemA" has a value of 100 in the database. Which I have assigned a value to problem, what I really want is if a user inputs 50 into an input field, that "ItemA" value will now show 150 when it is called back in a select query. I am unsure of how to add the value in a column and a users input together.

I am new to PHP and SQL, so please forgive me. Any help is greatly appreciated and I thank you for your time!

The PHP that I have:

```
<?

$payout = $_POST["payout"];
$payouts = $_GET["payout"];
$withdraw = $_POST["bank_withdraw"];
$cashspent = $_POST["cash_spent"];

$servername = "localhost";
$username = "*****";
$password = "*****";
$db = "*****";

$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $db);

if ($conn->connect_error){
    die("Connection failed: ". $conn->connect_error);
}

$sql = "UPDATE finances SET payout = '$payouts' + ? WHERE finance_id = 1";

$stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($conn);

if ( ! mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sql)){
    die(mysqli_error($conn));
}

mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "ii",
                       $payout,
                       $payouts
                       );

mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
```

In this example, I am trying to have it where a user is able to add the two values from what is already in the database.

```
Item in database (payout) = 100
Input from user = 50
Item from database + input from user = 150, showing in database
```

Answer (score 0):

if I understand your question correctly there are 2 parts:

1. Select payout from database and add it to the user input.
2. update the value in the database

For 1) select the payout from the database `$select_sql = "SELECT payout FROM finances WHERE finance_id = 1";` and you could use a variable such as `$increasedPayout` and assign this new variable `$increasedPayout = $payouts + $select_sql;`

and then for 2) use the `$increasedValue` variable in your SQL UPDATE statement.

```
$sql = "UPDATE finances SET payout = '$increasedPayout' WHERE finance_id = 1";
```